# Position image relative to previous image which is dynamically sized and positioned

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I have found numerous questions about relative positioning of images, yet they all rely on a parent DIV which fails in my case as you will see.

I also found various solutions for fixed ratio DIVs, those use padding-bottom leading to over-sized height in my case.

So here is my original situation (see e.g. https://www.giulietta-del-conte.com/). Essentially:

```
<body>
 <img alt="Logo" width=1280 height=853 src="/img/GdC-Logo.jpg">
</body>
```

With:

```
img {
  height:auto; 
  width:auto; 
  max-width:80%;
  max-height:80%;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
```

Now I want to position a second image (a banner) exactly below the first image. The banner has same width and much smaller height.

I have tried creating a parent div, but that does not work out. I cannot get it to the exactly required size, so I can resized and position the two image. I tried to create it with the right width and combined height. Yet it will not properly resized using max-width and max-height (becomes disproportional).

It is fairly easy to create a version which allows resizing in either direction, but I fail to get a version which allows resizing in both directions and centers the combined block.

Any idea? I did not want to create a combined image as a map.

Comment: Sidenote: You have an erroneous `</a>` in your HTML.

Comment: Just a copy/paste error. This is on the original page, but does not change anything here. Will correct above.

Comment: In the case of the two images (img + banner), do you want them both centered horizontally and vertically (as if both were a single image) or do you want the img centered and then the banner positioned below it?

Comment: As you say I would like them to be resized and centered as if they were just one image. Yet both will receive individual links and I don't want them combined into one due to Google image search.

Yet even if the first image would remain where it is now and the banner exactly below would be good enough.

Comment: Much clearer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is a hack. I changed the banner have the joint size of both pictures. Then I can correctly resize and center it. It remains to properly position the main (original) picture. Done. Solution visible on https://www.giulietta-del-conte.com/.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time here. So would be very grateful to know if the answer was the way you expected it to be.
Also do let me know if it wasn't the way you wanted. Thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="new 1.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
            <img id= "pic" alt="Logo" width="1280" height="853" src="https://www.giulietta-del-conte.com/img/GdC-Logo.jpg">
            <img id="banner" src="https://www.giulietta-del-conte.com/img/Scope.jpg" alt="banner" width="1280" height="200px">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
#pic {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#banner {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}
 div {
    height:911px;
    width:1280px;
    max-width:80%;
    max-height:80%;
    position:absolute;
    top:46%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried BR before, but it fails in combination with my dynamic (centered both ways) positioning. The banner then gets position relative to the mid point.

Comment: could you explain me what do you want between the banner and the picture? The space does remain preserved between the images even when u make the browser small.

Comment: I actually want both images touch each other, both same (dynamic) width, making them appear as one. But as explained above I don't want to create a combined image. The test page above shows the desired effect if the browser window is typical desktop/laptop size, but fails when you make the window very tall or very wide in ratio.

Comment: Please do check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the improved version. The issue is that the images are resized disproportionally, since the div will not preserve the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to do without using parent divs for centering. However it is possible to achieve the effect with a combination of flex and "normal" css. [Here's a working example](http://codepen.io/antidecaf/pen/pbBQNk).

You'll need a horizontally centered flex container (`.centered` in this example) that takes up 100% of the browser height. Nested in the flex container, add a non flex div (eg `display: block`). Because the non flex div is the sole item of the flex layout, it will be centered horizontally and vertically, while allowing you to create a separate non flex layout of elements inside it.

Now as long as the images have max-width set to 100% (no height specified) their proportions will be preserved whatever the width of their parent elements may be. Granted, I haven't done anything to limit vertical overflowing, but as long as the image proportions aren't crazy, this might be worth a try.

```css
/* For demo purposes */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.centered {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;            /* Needed for vertical centering */
  align-items: center;      /* Flex - vertical centering */
  margin: 0 auto;           /* Horizontally center the layout */
  justify-content: center;  /* Flex - horizontal centering of content */
  text-align: center;       /* Keep images centered in the event of layout width exceeding image width */
  max-width: 60%;           /* For demo purposes */
  background: #eee;         /* For demo purposes */
}

/* Nested non flex container allows you to create a separate layout inside the flex container */
.centered div {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500">  
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just don't get how to make sure the combined height of the images is limited to 80% of viewport.